# Does `C-x h` and `C-x-h` mean the same thing in Emacs ?

Tags: emacs, text-editor

> Does `C-x h` and `C-x-h` mean the same thing in Emacs ?

Why are some commands in Emacs specified without an `-`, while some are, like the example above ? Does it always mean the same thing ?

Comment: Could you please provide an example where this syntax is used? A command perhaps?

Comment: It is used in all cheat sheets written for Emacs.

Answer (score 3):

`C-x h` means hold the Control key pressed while you hit (press and release) the `x` key, and then hit the `h` key.

Emacs key notation does not use `C-x-h`; it is a mistake.  (But `C-H-x` is not a mistake, because `H-` is the Hyper modifier key - see below.)

The hyphen (`-`) is used after a key when the key is a **modifier key**. A modifier key is held down while the next key is hit. **`C-`** is the Control modifier key.  **`M-`** is the Meta modifier key (typically a keyboard Alt key). **`S`** is the Shift modifier key.  Those are the standard modifier keys.  Some keyboards have additional modifier keys, such as Hyper (`H-`) and Super (`s-`).

You can find such information by *asking Emacs*: `C-h r` to access the manual, then `i` to ask the index of the manual: type something and hit `TAB` to see what matching index entries there are. In this case: `C-h r i key TAB` shows you that `key` itself is an index entry - so hit `RET` (Enter key) to see information about keys, in particular, the answer to your question.

(Well, actually [this node](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/User-Input.html) of the manual tells you the answer to your question.  You could find it using `i key TAB` as the entry `keyboard input`.)